# Can't activate rack when running cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bundler

I can no longer run cucumber in my rails 3 app. I'm not sure exactly when it broke but I did do some rspec work that required me to use the webrat gem and it was working before that.

My error is:

```
$ cucumber  
Using the default profile...  
can't activate rack (~> 1.2.1, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.0.7", "railties-3.0.7"], already activated rack-1.3.0 for ["rack-test-0.5.7", "cucumber-rails-0.4.1"] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'  
gem 'sqlite3'  
gem 'devise'  
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'  
gem 'cancan'  

group :development, :test do  
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'  
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0' 
  gem 'webrat', ">= 0.7.2"  
  gem 'cucumber-rails'  
  gem 'capybara'  
  gem 'database_cleaner'  
  gem 'launchy'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  
  gem 'spork'  
end
```

Please let me know if I need to supply more info and I'll edit this.

I've tried specifying rack in my Gemfile but this doesn't seem to help and doesn't seem right. Also: If I modify my Gemfile I am running "bundle install" and then trying cucumber again. Is this the right workflow to solve this problem?

Can anyone please help?

Cheers,
Rim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in my IRC channel pointed me in the right direction.

Use the context of bundler (which I don't quite understand yet)

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

This works just fine :)